# Ksoap in Eclipse

Tags: android, ksoap

HI

i new to android. i want to use ksoap to connect to web service. i have seen a lot of example. but the bet which i am not able to figure out is how to install ksoap in eclips

so that i can import the ksoap libs

import org.ksoap2;

Answer (score 9):

You add any Jar-files to your project like this:

1. Open your project's properties (right click)
2. Choose 'Java Build Path'
3. Choose 'Libraries' tab
4. Click 'Add External Jar' button
5. Find and choose *.jar file.

Answer (score 2):

And the ksoap2 jar file can be found on this link:

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar&can=2&q=

Answer (score 0):

Copy the jar file into the project's libs folder if you are working with eclipse IDE.
jar file can be found here:[jar file ksoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar&can=2&q=)